# MS.Internal.WrappedException in <Pivot>.itemsSource

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying use pivot to view image.
But when I run the code, the debugger breaks at this line:

```
MainViewer.ItemsSource = QueueingImages;
```

And thrown this weird exception:

```
An exception of type 'MS.Internal.WrappedException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

This is the xaml I used:

```
<phone:Pivot Grid.Row="1" Name="MainViewer">
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="" FontSize="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="10" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding IMGSource}" Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Row="0">
                        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="{Binding ImageFlick}"
                                                 DragDelta="{Binding ImagePan}"
                                                 PinchDelta="{Binding ImageZoom}"
                                                 Tap="{Binding ImageTap}"
                                                 DoubleTap="{Binding ImageDoubleTap}"
                                                 />
                        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    </Image>
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding DownloadPercentage}" Maximum="100" Minimum="0" SmallChange="1" Visibility="{Binding IsCompleted}"/>
                </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

The "QueueingImages" is:

```
private ObservableCollection<ImageView> QueueingImages
```

Here is the ImageView Class:

```
class ImageView
{

    public ImageView(String id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String Id { get; private set; }
    public ImageSource IMGSource { get; private set; }
    public int DownloadPercentage { get; set; }
    public Visibility IsCompleted { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler Flicked;

    /*
    Flick="{Binding ImageFlick}"
    DragDelta="{Binding ImagePan}"
    PinchDelta="{Binding ImageZoom}"
    Tap="{Binding ImageTap}"
    DoubleTap="{Binding ImageDoubleTap}"
    */

    public void SetSource(System.IO.Stream s)
    {
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(s);
        IMGSource = bi;
    }

    public void ProgressHandler(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadPercentage = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    /////// Image Controls
    public void ImageFlick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        // Pass out Event
        if (Flicked != null)
            Flicked(sender, e);
    }

    public void ImagePan(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Panning");
    }

    public void ImageZoom(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Zooming");
    }

    public void ImageTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tapped");
    }

    public void ImageDoubleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Double Tapped");
    }

}
```

Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the detail which is contained inside the `WrappedException`? That should tell you where the real problem lies in your code.

Comment: There is also `System.Exception` and 3 other `WrappedException`.

Comment: You will need to give more detail or no-one will be able to help. What is the output of `ToString()` on the exception objects?

Comment: Ok, but I think that was the most details I can get. Anyway I figured out myself. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out.
The error is caused by the following code.

```
<toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
     <toolkit:GestureListener Flick="{Binding ImageFlick}"
         DragDelta="{Binding ImagePan}"
         PinchDelta="{Binding ImageZoom}"
         Tap="{Binding ImageTap}"
         DoubleTap="{Binding ImageDoubleTap}"
     />
</toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
```

It seems I CANNOT use binding under `toolkit:GestureListener`.
I remove the Bindings and everything's working perfectly:)